# Existence of projection

Tags: linear-algebra, projection

Suppose vector space $V$ over field $K$ has finite dimension. $W$ and $Z$ are subspaces of $V$ such that $\dim W \geq \dim Z$.
Show that there exist projection $p$ from $V$ to $V$ such that $p(W)=Z$.

Comment: When you say that $p$ is a projection, do you require that $p : V \to V$ is surjective? If $W$ has dimension strictly larger than $Z$, but $p(W) = Z$, then I do not think it is possible to have $p(V) = V$.

Comment: No, otherwise p had to has zero kernel, right? so the space we are projecting along would have to be zero space. I dont necessarily want that.

Comment: So what is meant by the word "projection" in this context?

Comment: projection is a map that is identity on space that we project on, and is 0 on the space we project along. If V is direct sum of some of two its subspaces A and B, then every vector from V v=a+b where a is in A and B is in B, then projection on A along B is p(v)=p(a+b)=a

Comment: Suppose such a projection were to exist. If $z \in Z$ then there exists $w \in W$ with $p(w) = w = z$. Thus $Z \subseteq W$. Now just choose $W$ and $Z$ with $\dim{W} \geq \dim{Z} > 0$ and $W \cap Z = \{0\}$ for a counterexample.

Comment: why p(w)=w? W is not necessarily the space we are projecting onto

Comment: if $z = 0$ then we may take $w = 0$ and if $z \neq 0$ then $z$ is in the space that we project onto? i am assuming from your comment above that a projection is the identity on anything outside of its kernel

Comment: Z is also not necessarily the space we project onto, projection is defined as: when V=A direct sum B, and a is a vector from A and b is vector from B and when we are projecting onto A along B then p(a+b)=a.

Comment: In this case, just take $W \subseteq B$ and $Z \neq \{0\}$.

Comment: you cant just take W to be something, you are given W and Z and then you have to give p

Answer (score 1):

Do you know the other (and usually used more often as a definition) characterization of a projection as a map such that $p^2 = p$?

First, assume that $W \cap Z = 0$.
So, start with a basis of $Z$ say $z_1,...,z_l$, then extend to include a basis of $W$ so that you have $z_1,...,z_l, w_1,...,w_m$ and then extend to complete a basis of $V$ so that your overall basis is $z_1,...,z_l, w_1,...,w_m, v_1,...v_n$. Now, define $p$ on the basis by

$$ p(x) = \begin{cases} 
      z_i & x = z_i \\
      z_i & x = w_i, i ≤ l \\
      0 & x = w_i, i > l  \\
0 & x = v_i
   \end{cases}$$

and extend by linearity. Check to see that $p^2 = p$. See if it's clear why $p(W) = Z$ and not just $p(W) \subset Z$.

Can you see how to modify this to make it work if the intersection isn't trivial? The only change there is to start your basis with that intersection, then extend to $Z$, then extend to $W$ then to $V$ and do some similar shuffling.

Comment: I am not sure about the step of extending Z to W, if Z is a line and W is plane, intersection is {0}, so we start with {0} then extend it to line, and what next? I cant have basis of W anymore with this vecotr from Z.

Comment: I should have worded as extend to a basis that includes $W$ in its span but the method still works. You start with a basis of $Z$ then extend to a basis that includes $Z$ and $W$, you define $p$ to map everything from the $Z+W$ basis back to $Z$ in a way that is surjective and you go from there.

Comment: So for your example, you have empty intersection. You add a vector $z$ to get the line. Then you add vectors $w_1, w_2$ for the plane, and then add any other basis vectors to complete the whole space. Then you define $p$ by $p(z) = p(w_1) = p(w_2) = z$ and then on any other basis vectors you define as $0$ (or even $z$ if you wanted!)